C# MSChart. How do I find the XY position of the Series Label for a StackedColumn ChartType?
I have a StackedColumn Chart. I would like to draw text at the X position of the Series centerpoint and a Y position near the top of the chart. I am having trouble figuring out where the Series XY position is.
The closest thing I have been able to achieve is shown below:

I achieved this by drawing the labels as follows:
    startX = chartRect.Left + (float)(chartDailyBuildRateDisplay.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(0));
    startY = chartRect.Top + 5;
    g.DrawRectangle(whitePen, startX, startY + 15, 120, 40);
    g.FillRectangle(steelBlueBrush, startX, startY + 15, 120, 40);
    g.DrawString(" Goal: " + LVDTGoal.ToString(), font, whiteBrush, startX, startY + 20);

    startX = chartRect.Left + (float)(chartDailyBuildRateDisplay.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(1));
    g.DrawRectangle(whitePen, startX, startY + 15, 120, 40);
    g.FillRectangle(steelBlueBrush, startX, startY + 15, 120, 40);
    g.DrawString(" Goal: " + RVDTGoal.ToString(), font, whiteBrush, startX, startY + 20);

etc.
Obviously I need to include something else like the Axis size or something like that? Any help would be appreciated.

I don't quite understand where you want the text. Would you please draw a simple mspaint image to illustrate? Maybe with some more columns to so it's clear what you want it to look like with higher values.

Ah, I see the problem. I started with ValueToPixelPosition(0) which I thought was the first Bar. It is not. I assume that is the xAxis itself. Changing my code to start at 1 for the first bar, solved the problem.

